# Does "Faulting Application" in Windows Event Viewer correlate to segmentation fault in software?

Tags: c++, windows, crash, segmentation-fault, event-viewer

A C++ application that we don't have the source code for is crashing.
The crash is being reported in the Windows Event Viewer:

[image]

More specifically, the report shows the following:

```
Faulting application name: SEP.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x586d8900
Faulting module name: SEP.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x586d8900
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000031ab0
Faulting process id: 0x13bc
Faulting application start time: 0x01d26abbb48ffc6b
Faulting application path: C:\Program\Program.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program\Program.exe
```

Based on this information, I'd like to make a conclusion about the software bug.   The software experienced a segmentation fault.

I would just like to confirm whether this information specifically alludes to a segmentation fault, and not something like uncaught exceptions, or exits with failure codes, or any other C++ signals (such as divide by zero (SIGFPE)).

To rephrase the question again:
Based on this log information, can I conclude with confidence that the program is crashing due to a segmentation fault and not any other reason?

Comment: The crash shown in the screenshot isn't of the same type as the crash shown in the body of the question.  I assume you're asking about the `0xc0000005` exception?  (If so, yes, that's an access violation, which I believe is equivalent to what POSIX calls a segmentation fault.  That is, an invalid memory location was accessed, or a valid memory location was accessed in an invalid way.)

Comment: Yes, I'm interested in 0xc0000005.  Apologies for the inconsistent picture.  I was looking for some kind of list on the event viewer exception codes, but nothing came up.  What you said confirms my thoughts as well.

Comment: There's a reference here: [NTSTATUS Values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588.aspx), though it doesn't go into much detail.